# scroll recycler view and edit child background giving null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, get-childitem

I'm trying to scroll a recycler view and change the background of a given item in the recycler view as it scrolls in sync to the android TTS engine, the scrolling works without issue but the changing background breaks (NPE) as soon as there are too many items in the view, I believe its because of how the recycler view destroys children but being a bit of a novice I'm not sure here is my code for scrolling the view

```
public void onInit(int initStatus) {
    if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
        //myExclusiveTTS.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
        myExclusiveTTS.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("onDone " + cardCountPosition +" list size " + SpeakGridDB.cardMakerList.size());
                            SpeakGridDB.recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(cardCountPosition).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
                            cardCountPosition ++;
                            if(cardCountPosition == SpeakGridDB.cardMakerList.size()){
                                System.out.println("onDone if " + cardCountPosition +" list size " + SpeakGridDB.cardMakerList.size());
                                cardCountPosition = 0;

                            }
                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                    System.out.println("onStart " + cardCountPosition +" list size " + SpeakGridDB.cardMakerList.size());
                    moveView();
                }
            });

    } else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Oops sorry! Text To Speech failed... SimpleAAC cannot fix this", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void moveView(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (cardCountPosition < SpeakGridDB.cardMakerList.size()){
                SpeakGridDB.recyclerView.getLayoutManager()
                        .smoothScrollToPosition(SpeakGridDB.recyclerView, null, cardCountPosition + 1);
                SpeakGridDB.recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(cardCountPosition).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_blue_border);

            }
            else{
                //this never gets called
                cardCountPosition = 0;
            }

        }
    });
}
```

my NPE comes from the moveView method @

```
SpeakGridDB.recyclerView.getLayoutManager()
.getChildAt(cardCountPosition).setBackgroundResource
(R.drawable.selected_blue_border);
```

if i only have 1,2,3 or 4 items in the view it will work without fail and my print outs look like this

```
I/System.out: onStart 0 list size 3
I/System.out: onDone 0 list size 3
I/System.out: onStart 1 list size 3
I/System.out: onStart 1 list size 3
I/System.out: onDone 1 list size 3
I/System.out: onDone 2 list size 3
I/System.out: onDone if 3 list size 3
```

any more than 4 (about how many items that fit in the screen) is crashes with the NPE but my printouts look identical can anybody suggest something i need to be checking before i set the background resource of the view

Answer (score 0):

found an answer to this on another post I'm now using

```
 SpeakGridDB.recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition
 (cardCountPosition).itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
```

taking the number from the view holder rather than the adapter which only counts the views in view